# Exporting to GLTF Causes Leg to Twist. How can this be prevented?

Tags: animation, export, rigify, gltf, actions

Whenever I export to GLTF, the character's right leg twists after the export is complete. This occurs across all actions. I'm using rigify. The leg is twisted in the export as well. What can cause such a thing?

When I paste the x-flipped version of the same pose, it fixes all animations, and I don't even have to make a new keyframe. But the problem reappears on export. Something is bugged, obviously. Any ideas?

This gif shows what it looks like before and after the export. Note that I'm not reimporting or anything. This is just what happens immediately after the export completes.
[image: Gif showing before and after export]

Comment: This looks like a bug — I'd recommend reporting it at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO, with the .blend if you can share that.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I've never done that before - do I do it through the issues tab?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I figured out the reporting system and have since reported it here. https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1386 I would still appreciate any advice at all though! I would not be surprised if I'm making other mistakes in how I'm approaching animation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug of the GLTF exporter.

Comment: @brockmann I can't be sure that's the case. Have you been able to reproduce it?

Comment: Seems Don is one of the developers. If you properly filed a bug report they will take care of that issue.

Comment: @brockmann It is a bit of a blocker for me right now, so I'd prefer to keep it open in case someone else has seen it and found a work-around.

Comment: I voted to re-open the question @Nubsy